# Implementing SAML into existing Java Tomcat Web App

Tags: java, netbeans, single-sign-on, saml

We already have an IDP. We already have a metadata.xml.
The Application uses Netbeans, Tomcat and Apache.  It is not Maven.  Just Java.
We need to implement SAML SSO into this non-Maven application.

What is the most straight forward solution?

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of Java libraries that allow one to integrate with a SAML IdP. Here is what comes to mind:

- Spring Security SAML: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-saml with a sample application demonstrating the functionality: https://github.com/UniconLabs/spring-security-saml-java-sp

Note that SS SAML uses OpenSAML v2 which has been long deprecated. There are plans to get it updated "soon", but nothing official yet.

- You may also use pac4j: http://www.pac4j.org/2.2.x/docs/clients/saml.html This is a Java library based on OpenSAML v3 that provides most if not all of SS SAML functionality in its own ways.

Comment: Sounds great.  We upgraded the app to Maven.  It's still using Spring Web MVC.  The web app is very simple with a landing page.  We're looking at https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-saml with a sample application.  I notice that when the sample app first opens, it allows the user to select the idp.  We certainly don't need that feature.  We have one default idp (metadata.xml) that we want to use and the landing page that must SAML authenticated.  Are there any other sample apps or better documentation?